# I have a error the development server response error code 500 in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, android-emulator

I am using React Native and encountered the following error on my android emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvyoq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyte3.png)

I tried several times and the same thing comes out on my cell phone scanning the QR

I also noticed that the folders are empty.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhzxZ.png)

Comment: Please make sure to include the images directly in your question instead of posting them on elsewehere and just linking them here. You can also just paste the error message here. Use the > to indent the text or take advantage of the formatting abilities of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The import module Path is incorrect please check.

'. /App/Redux/action' please check this path

Comment: I also noticed that the folders are empty.

Comment: can you share your App.js file code